# ORDS GET Procedure returning CLOB as JSON

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql, clob, oracle-ords

I'm having trouble calling a REST-GET service that uses a procedure that returns a CLOB in JSON. When the result has a few records, it runs ok, but if they are a lot of them, it crashes.

Oracle 12.1

I've defined a table with postal codes.
In this, each municipality identifier has a record with a postal code.
But in large municipalities, each one can have several postal codes, according to the address within the city.

For example,

- for the municipality of "Salvatierra de los Barros" (id = 6117), there's only 
    one registry with a zip code

- for the municipality of "Badajoz" (id = 6015), there are several records with:

* several different postal codes, for each village that depends  of "Badajoz", and

* several postal codes, corresponding to the different streets of "Badajoz".

In practice:

```
SELECT ID, CODPOSTAL, TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID, TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID,
       DENOUPOBLACIONAL, DENODIRECCION
  FROM EDUCOMUNES.TGEOCODPOSTALES
 WHERE TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID IN ( 6117, 6015 )

    ID CODPOSTAL  TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID DENOUPOBLACIONAL            DENODIRECCION
------ ---------- ---------------- --------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------
  3148 06175                  6117              61170001 SALVATIERRA DE LOS BARROS
    ID CODPOSTAL  TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID DENOUPOBLACIONAL            DENODIRECCION
------ ---------- ---------------- --------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------
  3108 06183                  6015              60150012 NOVELDA DEL GUADIANA
  3146 06181                  6015              60150014 SAGRAJAS
  3176 06194                  6015              60150016 VALDEBOTOA                  
 48558 06003                  6015              60150004 Badajoz                     MARIA LUISA DE CARVAJAL
 48562 06003                  6015              60150004 Badajoz                     MARIN DE RODEZNO
 48576 06001                  6015              60150004 Badajoz                     MAYOR
 48577 06001                  6015              60150004 Badajoz                     MELCHOR DE EVORA
 48579 06001                  6015              60150004 Badajoz                     MELENDEZ VALDES (Impares del 19 al final)  (Pares del 16 al final)
...
 48774 06011                  6015              60150004 Badajoz                     REPUBLICA DE CHILE

 1.166 filas seleccionadas
```

I have created a REST service to obtain the postal codes of a municipality.
This service invokes a stored procedure that performs the query, gets an XMLTYPE, 
applies JSON format, and returns it to the client as CLOB.

The call for the simple case "Salvatierra de los Barros", returns the information 
correctly, i.e., it returns the result of the query, and a status of success.
The call for the most complex case "Badajoz", gives an error.

Message in the REST log in SQL Developer:

```
  jul 06, 2018 1:41:10 PM  
  INFORMACIÓN: Error occurred during execution of: [CALL, BEGIN 
                           paq_tgeocodpostales.json_obtener_todos ( 
                           pe_idmunicipio => /*in:idmunicipio*/?,                            
                             ps_json_resultado => /*out:json_resultado*/?, 
                             ps_json_estado => /*out:json_estado*/? );
                             END;, 
                             [idmunicipio, in, class java.lang.Integer], 
                             [json_resultado, out, class java.lang.String], 
                             [json_estado, out, class java.lang.String]]
                             with values: {1=6015}
  jul 06, 2018 1:41:10 PM  
  INFORMACIÓN: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error  numérico o de valor
  ORA-06512: en línea 2

  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error  numérico o de valor
  ORA-06512: en línea 2
```

Note: If we invoke the procedure directly from an anonymous block it works 
correctly in both cases.

- in the case that it works, it saves a couple of lines,

- in the case that fails, it does not record any information.

In file  C:\app\client\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl.log,

- in the case that it works, it saves a couple of lines,
        "2018-07-10T11:30:17.410753+02:00
        Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 248 (LGWR switch)
          Current log# 2 seq# 248 mem# 0: C:\APP\CLIENT\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO02.LOG"

- in the case that fails, it does not record any information.

I have tried to modify some parameters by entering as Ords Administrator and
manipulating idle timeout times from 1800 to 3600 sec., and from
connection abandonment from 900 to 3600 sec .; however, it also fails.

Definition of the source table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "EDUCOMUNES"."TGEOCODPOSTALES" 
  ( 
  "CODPOSTAL" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "CHEQUEO_C01" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TGEOPROVINCIA_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DENOUPOBLACIONAL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DENODIRECCION" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "BUSCAR" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT "TGEOCODPOSTALES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  );
```

Definition of the packaged procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE 
PAQ_TGEOCODPOSTALES
IS

   FUNCTION OBTENER_DESCONOCIDO
   RETURN TGEOCODPOSTALES%ROWTYPE;
   /*   
   Returns the record corresponding to 'Unknown postal code'.
   */

   PROCEDURE JSON_OBTENER_TODOS
   (
   pe_idmunicipio     IN TGEOMUNICIPIOS.ID%TYPE,   
   ps_json_resultado OUT CLOB,
   ps_json_estado    OUT VARCHAR2
   );  
   /*
   Returns a list of all postal codes in a municipality in JSON format.
```

Returns completion status.
       */

```
END PAQ_TGEOCODPOSTALES;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY 
PAQ_TGEOCODPOSTALES
IS

   --====================== SUBRUTINAS ==========

-- ...other funcionality

   FUNCTION OBTENER_DESCONOCIDO
   RETURN TGEOCODPOSTALES%ROWTYPE
   IS
    registro TGEOCODPOSTALES%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN

        SELECT *
          INTO registro
          FROM TGEOCODPOSTALES
         WHERE BUSCAR LIKE '%DESCONOCIDO%';   

         RETURN registro;

   END OBTENER_DESCONOCIDO;

   PROCEDURE JSON_OBTENER_TODOS
   (
   pe_idmunicipio     IN TGEOMUNICIPIOS.ID%TYPE,    --==> NUMBER(38,0)
   ps_json_resultado OUT CLOB,
   ps_json_estado    OUT VARCHAR2
   )
   IS
      l_select        VARCHAR2 ( 1000 );
      l_from          VARCHAR2 ( 100 );
      l_where         VARCHAR2 ( 1000 );
      l_order_by      VARCHAR2 ( 100 );
      l_sql           VARCHAR2 ( 2000 );            
      xml_estado      XMLTYPE;
      xml_resultado   XMLTYPE;
      v_json          XMLTYPE;       
   BEGIN

      l_select := 'SELECT ID, CODPOSTAL, TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID, 
                   TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID, DENODIRECCION';
      l_from   := '  FROM EDUCOMUNES.TGEOCODPOSTALES';
      IF ( pe_idmunicipio IS NOT NULL )
      THEN
         l_where := '  WHERE TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID = ' || pe_idmunicipio;
      ELSE
         l_where := '  WHERE ID = ' || OBTENER_DESCONOCIDO().ID;
      END IF;
      l_order_by := '  ORDER BY CODPOSTAL, DENODIRECCION';
      l_sql := l_select || l_from || l_where || l_order_by;

      paq_xml_json.sql_a_xml ( l_sql, xml_resultado, xml_estado );
      ps_json_estado := paq_xml_json.xml_a_jsonvc( xml_estado );
      if not ( xml_resultado is null )
      then     
        v_json := paq_xml_json.xml_a_json ( xml_resultado );
        ps_json_resultado := paq_xml_json.xml_a_clob ( v_json ); 
      end if;     

   END JSON_OBTENER_TODOS;  

END PAQ_TGEOCODPOSTALES;
```

Successful example of direct call to the procedure from anonymous block:

```
set echo off
set verify off
set serveroutput on
SPOOL test_JSON_OBTENER_TODOS.txt
PROMPT 'Prueba de JSON_OBTENER_TODOS'

DECLARE
      json_resultado CLOB;
      json_estado    VARCHAR2 (3200);

   PROCEDURE PRINT_CLOB ( p_clob IN CLOB )
   IS
      MAXLONGBUFFER  INTEGER := 32767;
      v_longclob     INTEGER := 0;
      v_numlecturas  INTEGER := 0;
      v_bytes_restantes INTEGER := 0;
      v_desplazamiento  INTEGER := 0;
      i INTEGER := 1;        
   BEGIN
      v_longclob := dbms_lob.getlength ( p_clob );
      v_numlecturas := ( v_longclob / MAXLONGBUFFER );
      v_bytes_restantes := MOD ( v_longclob, MAXLONGBUFFER );
      IF ( MOD ( v_longclob, MAXLONGBUFFER ) <> 0 )
      THEN 
        v_numlecturas := v_numlecturas + 1;
      END IF;      

      v_desplazamiento := 1;
      while ( i < v_numlecturas )
      loop
        dbms_output.put_line( 
            dbms_lob.substr( 
                p_clob, 
                MAXLONGBUFFER, 
                v_desplazamiento ) ); 

        v_desplazamiento := v_desplazamiento + MAXLONGBUFFER;
        i := i + 1;
      end loop;

      if ( v_bytes_restantes <> 0 )
      then
        dbms_output.put_line( 
            dbms_lob.substr( 
                p_clob,                                                                 
                v_bytes_restantes,                                                              
                v_desplazamiento ) );                                                               
      end if;  
   END PRINT_CLOB;

BEGIN 
    dbms_output.ENABLE ( NULL );

    dbms_output.new_line;
    dbms_output.put_line ( 'List of postal codes of the municipality of Salvatierra de los Barros.' );
    dbms_output.new_line;
    PAQ_TGEOCODPOSTALES.JSON_OBTENER_TODOS( 
                                  6117,
                                  json_resultado, 
                                  json_estado );

    dbms_output.put_line ( json_estado );
    dbms_output.new_line;
    PRINT_CLOB ( json_resultado );

    dbms_output.new_line;
    dbms_output.put_line ( 'List of postal codes of the municipality of Badajoz.' );
    dbms_output.new_line;
    PAQ_TGEOCODPOSTALES.JSON_OBTENER_TODOS( 
                                  6015, 
                                  json_resultado, 
                                  json_estado );

    dbms_output.put_line ( json_estado );
    PRINT_CLOB ( json_resultado );
END;
```

The output:

```
Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.

List of postal codes of the municipality of Salvatierra de los Barros.

{"ROWSET":{"ROW":{"CODERR":0,"MENERR":"La consulta devolvió registros."}}}

{"ROWSET":{"ROW":{"ID":3148,"CODPOSTAL":06175,"TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID":6117,"TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID":61170001,"DENODIRECCION":null}}}

List of postal codes of the municipality of Badajoz.

{"ROWSET":{"ROW":{"CODERR":0,"MENERR":"La consulta devolvió registros."}}}
{"ROWSET":[{"ID":3006,"CODPOSTAL":06000,"TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID":6015,"TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID":60150004,"DENODIRECCION":null},
    {"ID":47952,"CODPOSTAL":06001,"TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID":6015,"TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID":60150004,"DENODIRECCION":"ARIAS MONTANO (Impares del 5 al final)  (Pares del 8 al final)"},
{"ID":47990,"CODPOSTAL":06001,"TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID":6015,"TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID":60150004,"DENODIRECCION":"BARTOLOME JOSE GALLARDO"},
...
{"ID":3195,"CODPOSTAL":06195,"TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID":6015,"TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID":60150018,"DENODIRECCION":null}]}
```

Definition of the REST service:

```
SPOOL PLANTILLAS_REST_codpostales.txt

DECLARE

    l_modulo             ORDS_METADATA.ords_modules.name%type;
    l_ruta_base          ORDS_METADATA.ords_modules.uri_prefix%type;
    l_patron_todos       ORDS_METADATA.ords_templates.uri_template%type; 
    l_patron_detalle     ORDS_METADATA.ords_templates.uri_template%type;
    l_metodo             ORDS_METADATA.ords_handlers.method%type;
    l_codigo_tipo_fuente ORDS_METADATA.ords_handlers.source_type%type; 
    l_codigo_fuente      ORDS_METADATA.ords_handlers.source%type;
    l_registros_por_pag  ORDS_METADATA.ords_modules.items_per_page%type;  --DEFAULT 25  
    par_idmunicipio      ORDS_METADATA.ords_parameters%rowtype;
    par_idcodpostal      ORDS_METADATA.ords_parameters%rowtype;
    par_resultado        ORDS_METADATA.ords_parameters%rowtype;
    par_estado           ORDS_METADATA.ords_parameters%rowtype;

BEGIN

        l_modulo                 := 'mod_geografico';
        l_ruta_base              := 'sisgeografico/';
        l_patron_todos           := 'codpostales/';     
    l_metodo                 := 'GET';
    l_codigo_tipo_fuente     := ORDS.source_type_plsql;
    l_registros_por_pag      := 0;

    par_resultado.name := 'RESULTADO';
    par_resultado.bind_variable_name := 'json_resultado';
    par_resultado.source_type   := 'RESPONSE';
    par_resultado.access_method := 'OUT';
    par_resultado.param_type    := 'STRING';

    par_estado.name := 'ESTADO';                            
    par_estado.bind_variable_name := 'json_estado';             
    par_estado.source_type   := 'RESPONSE';                     
    par_estado.access_method := 'OUT';                          
    par_estado.param_type    := 'STRING';                       


      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Definition of the REST services module' );
      ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE(
        p_module_name    => l_modulo,
        p_base_path      => l_ruta_base,
        p_items_per_page => l_registros_por_pag
      );

    dbms_output.new_line;
      dbms_output.put_line (      
    '**  Definition Of Service Template: Obtain All, With Entry Parameters **' );

    dbms_output.put_line (      
        'GET operation template for all postal codes of a municipality' );

    par_idmunicipio.name := 'IDMUNICIPIO';
    par_idmunicipio.bind_variable_name := 'idmunicipio';
    par_idmunicipio.source_type   := 'URI';
    par_idmunicipio.access_method := 'IN';
    par_idmunicipio.param_type    := 'INT';

    l_patron_todos := l_patron_todos || ':' || par_idmunicipio.bind_variable_name;

        ORDS.define_template(       
         p_module_name    => l_modulo,
         p_pattern        => l_patron_todos
        );

      dbms_output.new_line;
    dbms_output.put_line (
          '  ** Reading Controller With Entry Parameters **' );

    ORDS.define_handler(
    p_module_name    => l_modulo,
    p_pattern        => l_patron_todos,
    p_method         => l_metodo,
    p_source_type    => l_codigo_tipo_fuente,
    p_source         => 'BEGIN 
                         paq_tgeocodpostales.json_obtener_todos ( 
                         pe_idmunicipio => :' || par_idmunicipio.bind_variable_name || ',                            
                             ps_json_resultado => :' || par_resultado.bind_variable_name || ', 
                             ps_json_estado => :' || par_estado.bind_variable_name || ' );
                             END;',
    p_items_per_page => l_registros_por_pag);

              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Input parameter with the municipality identifier' );

              ORDS.define_parameter(
                p_module_name        => l_modulo,
                p_pattern            => l_patron_todos,
                p_method             => l_metodo,
                    p_name               => par_idmunicipio.name,
                    p_bind_variable_name => par_idmunicipio.bind_variable_name,
                p_source_type        => par_idmunicipio.source_type,
                p_access_method      => par_idmunicipio.access_method,
                p_param_type         => par_idmunicipio.param_type
              );

              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Output parameter with the result of the operation.' );  

              ORDS.define_parameter(
                p_module_name        => l_modulo,
                p_pattern            => l_patron_todos,
                p_method             => l_metodo,
                p_name               => par_resultado.name,
                p_bind_variable_name => par_resultado.bind_variable_name,
                p_source_type        => par_resultado.source_type,
                p_access_method      => par_resultado.access_method,
                p_param_type         => par_resultado.param_type
              );
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Output parameter with the status of the operation.' );  

              ORDS.define_parameter(
                p_module_name        => l_modulo,
                p_pattern            => l_patron_todos,
                p_method             => l_metodo,
                p_name               => par_estado.name,
                p_bind_variable_name => par_estado.bind_variable_name,
                p_source_type        => par_estado.source_type,
                p_access_method      => par_estado.access_method,
                p_param_type         => par_estado.param_type
              );


        COMMIT;      

END;
/
SPOOL OFF
```

Successful example of REST call from POSTMAN client:

```
http://localhost:8080/ords/educomunes/sisgeografico/codpostales/6117

        Output:
{
    "RESULTADO": "{\"ROWSET\":{\"ROW\":{\"ID\":3148,\"CODPOSTAL\":06175,\"TGEOMUNICIPIO_ID\":6117,\"TGEOUNIPOBLACIONAL_ID\":61170001,\"DENODIRECCION\":null}}}",
    "ESTADO": "{\"ROWSET\":{\"ROW\":{\"CODERR\":0,\"MENERR\":\"La consulta devolvió registros.\"}}}"
}
```

Example with REST call error from POSTMAN client:

```
http://localhost:8080/ords/educomunes/sisgeografico/codpostales/6015

Salida (Pretty JSON): Unexpected '<'
Status: 500 Server Error
Time:24906 ms
Size:370.1 KB
```

Comment: this is quite a mashup of things. Have you tried instead of using out params to just use htp.p(v_json) and print it directly?

Comment: Hi Kris, I'm sorry for the delay
Replacing with SYS.HTP.PRINT ( paq_xml_json.xml_a_clob ( v_json ) ); works fine for one record, but it does not seem to work for many records either.

Comment: The resultset has 1165 rows. How can i paginate this? Changing the value of ORDS_METADATA.ords_modules.items_per_page%type; doesn't seems to take effect. I suppose I must to paginate directly in the procedure.

Comment: Correct, pagination isn't automatically handled for plsql, only SQL based services